# How to format my post to reveal some text on clicking?

Tags: support, formatting

I have seen this in some help page of this site but haven't found it again.

What is the command (formatting) which makes some text reveal on click? (Isn't it something like `>! text` or something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, and it's [right there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) in the Markdown help:

> #### Spoilers
>
> To hide a certain piece of text and have it only be visible when a user clicks it, use the blockquote syntax with an additional exclamation point:
>
> ```
> At the end of episode five, it turns out that
> >! he's actually his father.
> ```

It's definitely more useful on the network sites about puzzles and movies than here...